# Problemas para instalar Laravel Homestead no ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

Acabei de instalar o ubuntu 16.10 e estou com problemas para instalar o Laravel Homestead. Estou com a versão 1.9.3 do Vagrant e 5.1.18 do Oracle virtual box. Até aqui sem problema, porém quando tento rodar o comando `vagrant box add laravel/homestead` recebo o seguinte erro:

```
The box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead"]
Error: Could not resolve host: atlas.hashicorp.com
```

Já pesquisei no google e no laracasts e nenhuma das respostas resolveu o meu problema. Se puderem me dar uma ajuda ficarei muito grato. Valew!

Comment: Pela mensagem que aparece, a maquina não consegue acessar o  atlas.hashicorp.com, você esta conectado na internet?